# Folders in lists

Tags: list

I need to create a list and segregate the data so that people in certain groups can edit only the rows of data that apply to their group.  I was told to create folders within the lists to do this, and then apply permissions to the folders.
However, when I create the folder, I am not only asked to provide a "Name" for the folder, I am also asked to fill in data in other fields that exist in my list - but it doesn't make sense to do that when creating the folder.  and the Name of the folder is populating a key field in my list, but again, is not relevant.

this doesn't seem to happen for all the lists I need to create folders for - why?  is there a way to prevent this and just create the folder?

is there a better way to accomplish my objective?  I've seen items re metadata vs folders - could metadata apply to this?  would I still be able to restrict users access to data that is not for their group?

thx

Comment: You might be confusing lists with libraries - they are a bit different, but that's off topic. Are you sure that you are using out of the box Folder content type and not a modified one?

Comment: I'm definitely talking about Lists - I've created the custom lists, and now need to segregate the data.

Comment: I'm definitely talking about lists - I created the custom lists.  and I need to segregate the data so that people can only add/edit certain rows in the lists.  and I pressed the New Folder icon on the Items tab - so I assume it's an out of the box function.

Comment: It would have been more straight forward question if the need to create folders is not explained! You can update the question for the benefit of the future readers!

Comment: Check the fields in the folder content type and either hide / remove them.

Comment: I explained that I was told to create folders to be able to segregate the data by the groups!

Comment: Right now I have 4 different sharepoint sites - each have the same set of custom lists in them.  Each site is used by a different group of people but they need to supply the same type of info in the lists.  it's been a pain to maintain, so we now want to combine all the data into one Sharepoint site but we still need to be able to segregate the data so that each group only has access to their data to update - we don't want them to accidentally update another groups's data in the lists.

Answer (score 0):

I think your list has custom forms set at the list level and not at the content type level. So this custom (could be just copy of the default / unedited new form) form is used for any content type including, 'Folder'. The same problem is discussed here.

[Issue: Custom List - click Add New Folder goes to Add New Item](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ca4256f-c7b8-491e-875c-7662ad81026b/issue-custom-list-click-add-new-folder-goes-to-add-new-item)

Comment: Thanks - the guy in this link has the same problem as me, but I don't understand the solution "You should be able to avoid this problem by making your custom form the default form for the content type, rather than the default form for the list.  In SPD, click on the content type, and set the default form from that screen."  how do you set a form as default? and is it in the Folder content type section or in the list content type section that I do something?

Answer (score 0):

I may be understanding the question wrong, but if you want to limit items in a list to only a certain group, you can create navigation links to different views of the same list, that only apply to a group...assuming that there is a field in the list for the group name. Then you can give permissions to view that link or view.

When you create a new view, go to the "Filter" drop down and make a condition where the Group Name (or whatever your field is for them) is equal to the name of that group. Then go to the view you created, copy the URL and paste it into a nav link. That's how we did this, anyway.

[image]

Comment: It sort of works, however once the user selects a link and are in a view they can then change views from the view drop down list and then they can access other group's views - is there anyway to restrict views?   and it's good if there is only one view per list per group, but I have several views per list, so I would need to recreate those views for each group and then create links to each one.  would folders be less maintenance?

Comment: The folders solution, then, is probably more suited for your needs. I was just trying to think of an alternate way to achieve separation. Sorry man, hope you find your solution!

Comment: Thanks.... so I go back to the original question then.... when I create the folder, I am not only asked to provide a "Name" for the folder, I am also asked to fill in data in other fields that exist in my list - but it doesn't make sense to do that when creating the folder. and the Name of the folder is populating a key field in my list, but is not relevant to that field... it should populate a different column - like Folder Name or something...

this doesn't seem to happen for all the lists I need to create folders for - why? is there a way to prevent this and just create the folder?